# how to fetch two table value from two while loop

Tags: php, php-5.2

I have two table,from this code i fetch the values from two table but one table value i am getting **$data[]=$row;**(i got value here) but one more table value i can't get...**$fstname=$r['emp_firstname'];**(not getting ans).fstname value it should be return null.

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 include('dbconfig.php');
 if(empty($_SESSION['email'])){
   header('Location:login.php');
 }
 $status = $_POST['status'];

 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM task WHERE  t_delete_on='0' AND t_status='$status'");
 $count=mysql_num_rows($sql);
 $return = array();
  if($count > 0){
   
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
     $data[]=$row;
      }
      $return=array('status'=>'success','count'=>$count,'data'=>$data);
      echo json_encode($return);
  }else{
   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM task WHERE  t_delete_on='0' AND t_status!='3'");
   $count=mysql_num_rows($sql);
   if($count > 0){
   while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
      $data[]=$row;
      }
      $return=array('status'=>'bending','count'=>$count,'data'=>$data);
      echo json_encode($return);
   }
  }
  
  
?>
```

Comment: why you can't use join query

Comment: i don't know ,how to use join query.....

Comment: print $assign_to than tell me what value u got

Comment: can you please tell us which is common column in these 2 tables.

Comment: See now from my code,$data it will be written like this  count
 
 1
data
 
 [Object { id="2",  t_id="STV2",  t_assign_to="AE097",  more...}]

Comment: now i want to select like this,SELECT * FROM task_employee WHERE emp_id='$t_assign_to' ,how to get the value and how to return this value